# Why does the Root Navlink always gets the active class on React-Router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

These are the Codes (And I have styled the active class in css)

[image]

```
<globalData.Provider
  value={{
    getLogin: getLogin,
    setName: setName,
    setNumber: setNumber,
    setPassword: setPassword,
    setTerms: setTerms,
    user: user
  }}
>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={login ? <HomePage />: <Login/>} />
      <Route path="/about/" element={<About />} >
        <Route path="vivekpage" element={<ViveksPage />} />
        <Route path="sujanpage" element={<SujansPage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/*" element={<HomePage />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</globalData.Provider>
```

nav

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <NavLink to='/' >Home</NavLink> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <NavLink to="/about" >About</NavLink>
    </li>
    <li>
      <NavLink to="/contact" >Contact</NavLink>
    </li>
    <li>
      {!user ? <NavLink to="/login" className="user"> 
        <i className="fa-regular fa-user"></i>
      </NavLink>: ""}
    </li>
  </ul> 
</nav>
```